# How to replace some value for #N/A in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I imported a matrix from MatLab to excel and because MatLab treats missing values as 'NaN's the matrix is filled with 'NaN' strings, which are no treated in excel as missing values. How can I replace it, perhaps using replace, by excel's #N/A ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit `Ctrl+H` to open the replace dialog box and enter `NaN` in the `Find what:` field and in the `Replace with:` field input `=na()`

Comment: such an easy and slick approach but i totally forgot